# Xubuntu Toshiba Satellite Pro L350 graphical glitches

Tags: xubuntu, intel-graphics, 14.10, toshiba

After upgrading from Xubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 some black signs appear on the windows.

```
$ dmidecode
...
  System Information
  Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
  Product Name: Satellite Pro L350
...

$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 07)

$ cat /var/log/Xorg.1.log | grep AIGLX
(II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what the problem looks like?

Answer (score 1):

There was some problem in the graphic acceleration of XFCE with this computer.

The solution was to disable compositing that gives you many effects like transparency and shadows

Go to: **Applications -> Settings -> XFCE Settings Manager**
Remove the check from **Enable compositing effects**

More information here:

[Are there 3D effects on Xubuntu? (hardware-accelerated graphics)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62502/are-there-3d-effects-on-xubuntu-hardware-accelerated-graphics)